# Use QTableWidget to get user input

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyqt4

could anyone give a quick tutorial on how i would be able to set up a QTablewidget the the user could enter tows of data (records) and then how i would dump that data into a database?

i am a beginner in python, and such an example would surly get me going. i thinking of working with PyQt, SqlAlchemy and MySql. i would prefer not to use Camelot because as a beginner i like to get my hands dirty. and i am choosing MySql over SQLite because in my sql i have an independent way of viewing the records my application inserts, unlike SQLite from what i understand, however i am open to suggestions.

i have been searching online for a few days now (just a coupla hours eache time), but couldn't find any good teachers.

i hope you could help.

Cheers,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a tutorial for this specific task. Just make sure understand how to do every individual part of what you want to do, and you'll be able to figure out how to mix everything.

If you haven't, you should read [the sqlalchemy tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html). I will teach you the basics on how to use the database. If you want a way to view the content of the database, there are some for sqlite too, like [sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/). If you just want to toy with a database, I would advice sqlite which doesn't need you to manager the server daemon.

You should also learn to manipulate [QTableWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html). If the doc is not enough and you need examples, remember that pyqt code is directly translated from the C++ code, so any C++ example will work for you (as long as you adapt the syntax). In fact, the examples in PyQt docs aren't translated. You can check out this question for more details on that : [Translate C++/Qt4 examples to PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657861/translate-c-qt4-examples-to-pyqt4) .

Once you know both, you'll easily find out how to use both in the same program.